# Unityでスクリプトがアタッチされたオブジェクトを探すにはどうすればいいですか？

Tags: unity3d

初めての質問です、よろしくお願いします。

操作の質問で申し訳無いのですが、ユニティちゃん2Dのデモプロジェクトをダウンロードして参考にしつつ勉強にしています。

そこに入っている「Demoプロジェクトについて.pdf」の中で、
「DemoUnityChan2Dゲームオブジェクトに Demo.csがアタッチされています。」
という説明があり、Demo.csは見つかるのですが、
「DemoUnityChan2Dゲームオブジェクト」がどこにあるのか分かりません。

そこでタイトルの質問なのですが、スクリプトの方からアタッチされている
オブジェクトを探す方法はないのでしょうか？

オブジェクトの方からは、Scriptのファイル名をクリックすれば表示してくれます。

簡単なことなようですが、分かりません。
ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DemoUnityChan2DのGameObject(プレハブ)は、
Assets > UnityChan2D > Demo > Prefabs の中にあります。

目的のアセットの探し方についてですが、プロジェクトビューの右上に検索窓があるので
そこに、探しているアセット名(今回であれば『DemoUnityChan2D』)を入力することで、一致した項目がリストアップされます。これが一番簡単な方法です。

スクリプトからオブジェクトを探す方法については、
既にシーン上に存在するオブジェクトなら、
プロジェクトビューの該当するスクリプトを右クリック > Find References In Scene で
検索することができます。(検索から元の状態に戻すにはヒエラルキービュー上部の検索窓をクリア)

シーン上に存在しないオブジェクトの場合は、Unityエディタの標準機能にはないので、エディタを拡張して機能を追加する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。検索窓を使う方法は、質問してから気付きました。(ProjectViewが横長なので目に入らなかった) 名前が分かっている場合はこの方法でOKですね。 シーンにない場合は、見つけられないようですね。

Answer (score -6):

困った時のテラシュールブログ様をどうぞ。
http://tsubakit1.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/09/01/233000

Comment: ありがとうございます。 このブログは役に立ちそうですが、ReferenceViewer というのは、エラーになってしまいました。 スクリプトの場合は、Find Reference In Sceneで探すのが良さそうですね。

Comment: 回答を記述しないとそのサイトがなくなったときに、役に立たない回答になります。yasuさんのおっしゃる通り主要部分を記述し、そのサイトを参考にしたということを書いてください。